# AngularJS project architecture

Tags: angularjs

I want to make a online booklibrary with angular and WebAPI.

I finished the guest application, now I want to make a administration page(/app), so only administrators could access it.

**How am I supposed to organize the architecture?** Now I have a single app, "appname.com/books , /cart...). Should I make a new Controller with route, in the same application, so admins would access it through: "appname.com/admin", or should I make a new app?

Any reading material on this subject would be very helpful.

Comment: This is a good article you should read [Techniques for authentication in AngularJS applications](https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/techniques-for-authentication-in-angularjs-applications-7bbf0346acec). You could separate the controllers in modules, but definitely don't need a second app. There is also this module that is worth taking a look [angular-permission](https://github.com/Narzerus/angular-permission)

Comment: Some discussion on the use  of multiple ng-apps have been discussed [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/239056/angularjs-structuring-a-web-application-with-multiple-ng-apps). There are many discussion around the web on the best structure for ordering the angular app structure: I prefer something like the structure described [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure). You can set permissions on which users can access a page using permissions in $routeProvider.